# Can I query in ArcGIS Online for features that have attachments

Tags: arcgis-online, query, attachments

I have a feature service in ArcGIS Online that has attachments enabled.  We upload photos of sidewalk trip hazards that have been painted by the city.

I have several queries setup with the Query widget to search for the date sidewalks were painted and other filters, but I want to be able to search for features that have photos attached.

Is there a way to query for and quickly locate features that have attachments without having to click through them until I see one with an attachment link?

Comment: You could do something like this linked Show Attachments as fields where you could detect if the field had a value or no value at all https://community.esri.com/docs/DOC-7445-show-attachments-in-web-map-popup

Comment: That link provides an option to view the attachments per feature selected individually rather that locating all features that have attachments.

Comment: I would do what Russ said, check to see if the field has a value or not.do not show NULL values.

Comment: Did you want to query in ArcGIS online or what you be okay with export in viewing outside of the Online environment?

Comment: I can already view which records have attachments by relating the ATTACH table in ArcMap, but I want to be able to see them in ArcGIS Online specifically.

Comment: Will that GP tool run automatically every time a picture is attached?

Comment: I dont think it detects change, I think you could set it up to run on a schedule and have the feature layer on a refresh interval so the changes are picked up and refreshed in maps that are currently open.

Comment: I guess I could just create a second relationship between the ATTACH table and the parent table and then publish the ATTACH table as a feature service and then run queries off of it in ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Just a reminder that if you wanted to do filters or symbolizing on a layer through their related records this is currently not supported. You will need to have it at the parent level.

Comment: Yeah I know that, can't wait for the day when that gets addressed.  But if I could setup a query to at least identify the parent records with attachments and then search for those records within AGOL I would be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally revisited this and was able to create a solution using a definition query on my layer that is related to the ATTACH table.  I simply had to apply this definition query to the layer:

```
GlobalID in (Select REL_GLOBALID FROM featureclass__ATTACH where ATTACHMENTID > 0)
```

This creates a layer that only shows features that have a related attachment, in this case pictures.  The layer updates as new attachments are added and the database is compressed.  [See this thread for more information.](https://community.esri.com/thread/117274#comment-851677)

Answer (score 0):

The question is old and probably no longer needed.  However, given how easy this is in 2019 with a little bit of puzzle solving, I will list one way of doing this:

**Get Feature Attachments**

1. Get the service URL of the feature/layer.  This is through the ArcGIS online service.
2. Craft new URL as the combination of the following strings: HTTP:// [service URL]/[Feature Object ID]/attachments?f=json&token=
3. Visit URL and this will give you a text string of the feature with a list of attachments.
4. Run this for all of the features you are querying.

**Scan multiple URLs and retrieve its results:**

Use a combination of Excel (2013 and later) and its WEBSERVICE function. Excel has filtering abilities.

5. Filter out features with no attachments.